# how can I use vue router to redirect to another website?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, router

I'm using vue router in a project and I noticed that when I used the redirect property it redirected me to the same website.
for example if I have

```js
import {
  createRouter,
  createWebHistory
} from "vue-router";
import Home from "@/views/Home.vue";
import Commands from "@/views/Commands.vue";

const routes = [{
  {
    path: "/google",
    redirect: "https://www.google.com",
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

it will redirect me to domain.com/https://www.google.com
instead of straightly going to https://www.google.com
is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following fixed OP's issue.

```js
const routes = [{
  {
    path: "/google",
    beforeEnter: () => {
      window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'
    },

  },
];
```

Using [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard).